# NoSuchFieldError: pathPatternParser in WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration after upgrade from spring-boot 2.5.5 to 2.6.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When upgrading to Spring-Boot from 2.5.5 to 2.6.1, I encounter the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pathPatternParser
```

I use Spring Boot Actuator, which uses class WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration in the autoconfigure dependency (spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure). On line 68 (decompiled class), the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration.pathPatternParser` field is used, which to my understanding causes the exception.

```
return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes, corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath), shouldRegisterLinksMapping, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.pathPatternParser);
```

If I check the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` class, I can only see the following usage of the `PathPatternParser` class, but no field declaration.

```
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
            if (this.mvcProperties.getPathmatch().getMatchingStrategy() == MatchingStrategy.PATH_PATTERN_PARSER) {
                configurer.setPatternParser(new PathPatternParser());
            }
```

Is this a bug?

I will try to use Spring-Boot 2.6.0, 2.5.7 and 2.5.6 and see what the behavior on those versions is. I will update this issue with the information

Comment: I think I found something. Apparently a module of my project uses camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.12.0 which depends on several 2.5.5 Spring-boot components, including spring-boot-autoconfigure, which is probably causing class-path loading conflicts. Will investigate further.

Comment: Yes, this one uses spring-boot-starter:2.5.5. The newer camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.13.0 uses spring-boot-starter:2.5.6 which is not sufficient. See: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot-starter/3.13.0 I will try to force it to use the 2.6.x version by excluding this dependency and hope that works.

Comment: any update on this? we ran into the same problem after upgrading spring-boot